# How to get the statuscode and success message using curl in R

Tags: r

```
curlHandle <- getCurlHandle(ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
url = "http://www.google.com"
Responseresult=postForm(url,curl=curlHandle,style="POST")
```

This is the code that I have used and I want to get the status code and the success or failure message that is sent by the server but by only using curl.

Comment: Any reason to use curl? The httr package provides all these features. https://github.com/r-lib/httr

Comment: Yes, I have to use only curl as there is some authentication problem in the client network and it does't allows other libraries.

Comment: Can you help me I just was the status code and the msg that has been sent by the server.

Comment: The status code and message is contained in the HTML inside `Responseresult` - you can parse the HTML to get the code and message.